# MFC read file and display it as HEX (hexdump)

Tags: mfc, hexdump

I need to read binary file and display bytes at certain offset so i can change that bytes and then save an updated file. I don't really understand how can i achieve that. I'm using MFC/VS 2008

So, i'am opening file using WinApi and getting its content to BYTE buffer. But i'm not sure how to print data at certain offset to (for example) an editbox and the main quesiton - how to edit this data (like in HEX editor) and save updated file.

```
 CFileDialog FileDlg(TRUE, "*", "*", OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST);
    if(FileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CString pathName = FileDlg.GetPathName();
        //MessageBox(pathName, NULL, MB_OK);
        // Implement opening and reading file in here. 
        //Change the window's title to the opened file's title.
        //CString fileName = FileDlg.GetFileTitle();
        //SetWindowText(fileName);
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(pathName.GetString(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, NULL,
            NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
        if(!hFile)
            return;
        DWORD dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
        BYTE *Content = (BYTE *)malloc(dwSize);
        DWORD dwRead;
        if(!ReadFile(hFile, Content, dwSize, &dwRead, NULL))
            return;

    }
```

Comment: Wait a minute i'll fix my question to be more precise.

Comment: At least show the code you use for opening the file. To convert bytes to Hex representation, use `sprintf(displaybuf, "%02X", byte);` where byte is `char` or `unsigned char`

Comment: Thanks, but how a can fill editbox with this data and make it editable as in Hexdump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with owner draw ListBox (size=fixed-sized, sort=false)

```
class CListHex : public CListBox
{
public:
    std::vector<BYTE> Buffer;
    CRect SaveItemRect;
    CEdit Edit;
    int Index;

    void setup()
    {
        if (Edit.m_hWnd && IsWindow(Edit.m_hWnd))
            return;
        Edit.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_CENTER, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, 1);
        Edit.SetFont(GetFont());
        Edit.SetLimitText(2);
        SetItemHeight(0, 21);
    }

    void read()
    {
        HANDLE hfile = CreateFile(L"in.txt", GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) //****CHANGED****
        {
            DWORD size = GetFileSize(hfile, NULL);
            Buffer.resize(size);
            ReadFile(hfile, &Buffer[0], size, 0, NULL);
            CloseHandle(hfile);
            for (int i = 0; i <= (int)Buffer.size() / 16; i++)
                AddString(0); 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(L"error");
        }
    }

    void write()
    {
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"out.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) //****CHANGED****
        {
            WriteFile(hFile, &Buffer[0], Buffer.size(), 0, 0);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(L"error");
        }
    }

    void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT di)
    {
        SaveItemRect = di->rcItem;
        CRect r = di->rcItem;
        r.right = r.left + r.Width() / 16;

        HBRUSH brush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(di->hDC, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
        FillRect(di->hDC, &di->rcItem, brush);

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            unsigned int cursor = di->itemID * 16 + i;
            if (cursor >= Buffer.size())
                break;
            CString s;
            s.Format(L"%02X", Buffer[cursor]);
            DrawText(di->hDC, s, s.GetLength(), r, DT_EDITCONTROL|DT_CENTER|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE);
        }
    }

    void OnLButtonDown(UINT f, CPoint p)
    {
        CListBox::OnLButtonDown(f, p);
        setup();

        int w = SaveItemRect.Width() / 16;
        CRect r = SaveItemRect;
        r.right = r.left + w;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (r.PtInRect(p))
            {
                unsigned int index = GetCurSel() * 16 + i;
                if (index >= Buffer.size())
                    return;
                Index = index;
                GetParent()->SetRedraw(0);
                CString s;
                s.Format(L"%02X", Buffer[Index]);
                Edit.SetWindowText(s);
                Edit.SetWindowPos(0, r.left, r.top, r.Width(), r.Height(), SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                Edit.SetFocus();
                GetParent()->SetRedraw(1);
                break;
            }
            r.OffsetRect(w, 0);
        }
    }

    //******CHANGED******       
    void MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT m) { m->itemHeight=21; }
    int  CompareItem(LPCOMPAREITEMSTRUCT) { return 0; }
    //******CHANGED******       

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CListHex, CListBox)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

In addition,

- You can add subclass for `CEdit`
- Override `CMyEdit::OnKillFocus()` to close the edit box
- Override `CMyEdit::OnChar` to accept hexadecimal characters only
- Read Edit string then convert to `unsigned char` and assign it to `Buffer[Index]`.
- Override `CListHex::OnVScroll` to close the edit box

**//CHANGED:**

To create the function try to do it manually, to make sure it get the right flags:

`list.Create(WS_VSCROLL | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_USETABSTOPS | LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED , CRect(10, 10, 450, 350), this, 1001);
list.read();`

Comment: Thanks, i tried first snippet with multiline edit-box with scroll and this works so i now see the hex representation of the file. Now i'll try to put all things together and make it work in the way i need.

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani, sure, i would like to see that.

Comment: I changed the answer, old answer is still available here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30629152/revisions (scroll to the bottom to see first revision)

Comment: Strange, I've added a listbox, added class declaration to .h file, message map to .cpp file ( also  buttons for read and write procedures) but when i'm trying to read file I've got debugger error on void AFXAPI AfxUnlockGlobals(int nLockType). What could it be?

Comment: I am not sure what's that error. I had a couple of errors in the code, I should check file's creation with **`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`** (see updated answer). Also try creating the listbox manually, using create

Comment: I think this is related to Addstring(0).

Comment: I've used your edited code and created list manually as u said (only adjusted size) but it displays wrong [link](http://i.imgur.com/5awHEzj.jpg)

Comment: You should make the list box as wide as the dialog, because it needs to fit 16 columns in there. It's a simple ownerdraw listbox, debug `DrawItem` to see what's wrong. You can remove the line for `SelectObject(brush...)` and `FillRect`. By the way, it won't work for files bigger than 1 mega byte because of scroll bar limitation, but you can get around if that.

Comment: At the moment it makes no difference which size the listbox has, but i think i will do some improves if i'll need them later, so thank you very much for the concept and for code!